# Importing key/value complexType definition from WSDL in WCF and Biztalk

Tags: java, wcf, wsdl, biztalk

I've been struggling with this for days without any idea in how to solve it. Basically I have the following WSDL service definition:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2.0-1 (tags/2.2.0u1-7139; 2012-06-02T10:55:19+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-2 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2.0-1 (tags/2.2.0u1-7139; 2012-06-02T10:55:19+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-2 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. --><definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://sample.org/schemas/2012" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://sample.org/schemas/2012" name="SampleServiceImplService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://sample.org/schemas/2012" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/sampleServices_war_exploded/sample?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="ExecuteSample">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:ExecuteSample"/>
</message>
<message name="ExecuteSampleResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:ExecuteSampleResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="SampleException">
<part name="fault" element="tns:SampleException"/>
</message>
<portType name="SampleService">
<operation name="ExecuteSample">
<input wsam:Action="http://sample.org/schemas/2012/SampleService/ExecuteSampleRequest" message="tns:ExecuteSample"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://sample.org/schemas/2012/SampleService/ExecuteSampleResponse" message="tns:ExecuteSampleResponse"/>
<fault message="tns:SampleException" name="SampleException" wsam:Action="http://sample.org/schemas/2012/SampleService/ExecuteSample/Fault/SampleException"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="SampleServiceImplPortBinding" type="tns:SampleService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="ExecuteSample">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
<fault name="SampleException">
<soap:fault name="SampleException" use="literal"/>
</fault>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="SampleServiceImplService">
<port name="SampleServiceImplPort" binding="tns:SampleServiceImplPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/sampleServices_war_exploded/sample"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

With the following accompanied XSD file definition:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.2.0-1 (tags/2.2.0u1-7139; 2012-06-02T10:55:19+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.6-2 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. --><xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://sample.org/schemas/2012" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://sample.org/schemas/2012">
<xs:element name="ExecuteSample" type="tns:ExecuteSample"/>
<xs:element name="ExecuteSampleResponse" type="tns:ExecuteSampleResponse"/>
<xs:element name="SampleException" nillable="true" type="tns:faultInfo"/>
<xs:complexType name="ExecuteSample">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="values">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="key" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="value" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ExecuteSampleResponse">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="faultInfo">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Ok, the documents looks fine, we define a complexType named ExecuteSample (the request type) that contains two members, name and values, the last one is another complex type with an entry named 'entry' with key and values.

This looks like a dictionary, and in fact is a dictionary. It even uses the 'suggested' way of exposing dictionaries with the only difference that is wrapped inside an 'entry' parameter.

Well, guess what, WCF svcutil neither biztalk can recognize the WSDL. SVCUtil and Visual Studio fails with a very stupid error telling me something like:

```
Warning 1   Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://sample.org/schemas/2012']/wsdl:portType[@name='SampleService']   C:\src\biztalk\ConsoleApplication6\ConsoleApplication6\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.svcmap    1   1   ConsoleApplication6
```

The biztalk WSDL import wizard fails without any error message, just telling me that something was wrong...

I've tried everything and looked everything possible in the web, nothing really pops.. I'm desperate and have no idea what the hell is happening, everything looks fine but is not working...

Weird... any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add targetNamespace to the schema tag in the types section of the wsdl.

```
<types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamepace="http://blah.org">
    ...
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
```